# How to get the header section title from selected tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a tableview which has several section. What I want is when I select a particular tableview cell from section I want title header of that section. I looked several SO question but didn't find out anything useful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get title with following code on tableviewcell click method

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header =[self.tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
NSLog(@"Header text = %@", header.textLabel.text);
```

In Swift

```
let sectionHeaderView = table.headerViewForSection(indexPath.section)
let sectionTitle = sectionHeaderView?.textLabel?.text
```

Comment: Just returns ```null``` for me.

Comment: it returns `nil` for me :(

Comment: have you implemented number of section delegate method ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following to get title if you are using "titleForHeaderInSection" table delegate :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let title = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: indexPath.row)

    }
```

Comment: This is somewhat correct but not quite (at least in Swift 5.2)—one needs to make this call using the `dataSource` property on the table view, as `UITableViewDataSource` has the method `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)`: so, `let title = tableView.dataSource?(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 : using cell button click**

```
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(.zero, to:self.mytable)
    let indexPath12 = self.mytable.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

    let intSection : Int = (indexPath12?.section)!
    let intRow : Int = (indexPath12?.row)!

    let myHeaderView = tableView(self.mytable, viewForHeaderInSection: indexPath?.section)
    let labels = myHeaderView?.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UILabel }

    var sectioTitle = ""
    for label in labels! {
        // you will get your title
        sectioTitle = label.text!
    }
```

**Swift 4 : using uitablview didselect method**

```
    let myHeaderView = tableView(self.mytable, viewForHeaderInSection: indexPath?.section)
    let labels = myHeaderView?.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UILabel }

    var sectioTitle = ""
    for label in labels! {
        // you will get your title
        sectioTitle = label.text!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue in a unit case.  My use case: no custom header and using the `UITableViewDataSource` method `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` to return a string for each section.  `headerView(forSection:)` returns `nil` but `numberOfSections` returns the correct number of sections, `rect(forSection:)` returns the correct frame, and, most puzzling, the visual debugger shows the sections as type `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

I was finally able to retrieve the titles for my sections by calling the `dataSource` method `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)`:

```
tableView.dataSource?(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: 0)
```

Seemingly odd behavior, as it seems like `UIKit` is using `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` to create headers when just a string is passed to the `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` method.  One would think you'd be able to retrieve them using `headerView(forSection:)`.